# Change a Window background color, given a IntPtr handle

Tags: c#, .net, windows, graphics, gdi

In c#, I have a handle to a window ( an IntPtr ), I want to change the background color of that window.  How can I do this?

I can get the GDI graphics object for that handle like so:

Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(theHandle);

So I should somehow be able to change the background color from this?

I also want to ensure the background color remains even after the window moves,resizes,repaints etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there's a way to do this directly with a native (C/C++) window (i.e. there is no native GDI analogue to Control.BackColor).

From looking in Reflector it appears that Control uses the BackColor property to respond to the various [WM_CTLCOLOR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432504.aspx)* messages (e.g. WM_CTLCOLOREDIT). So, if you want to change the background color of a native control, you may need to subclass that window and respond to that same message. If the native window is not a control, you'll still need to subclass the window, but you'd have to handle [WM_PAINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534901(VS.85).aspx) or [WM_ERASEBKGND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648055(VS.85).aspx) instead.

Try [this thread on programmersheaven.com](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/csharp/216293/216293/subclass-an-unmanged-window-in-c-/?S=B20000) for a suggestion on how to subclass a native window from C#.

Answer (score 0):

Create a control class with the Control.FromHandle method and then set the property.

Something like...

```
    Control someControl = Control.FromHandle(myHandle);
    someControl.BackColor = SystemColors.Black;
```

Comment: This doesn't work - probably because the handle I have is not to a .Net created window (so someControl comes back null)